# Google Sheet script won't setvalue of a cell that is being edited google script

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet that allows instructors to rate students level of competence on various items. The cells in question have Data Validation creating drop down lists of the 5 different levels. My sheet and script are working nicely except one instance I found where if I have clicked the cell and the drop down list shows up, the script won't do a setValue() on that cell.

Here is a test script that replicates the behavior:

```
function testing(){
     var gl = "Competent";
     var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
        .getSheetByName("StudentList")
        .getActiveRange();
      ss1.setValue(gl);
};
```

If the dropdown list has been initiated and then you run this function, it will not update the current cell and will put a blue box at the upper left of the cell with the Cell address.[Example of Blue box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pn2pg.png) If you have only clicked on the cell, the function will update the cell properly.
Any ideas or fixes?
I tried activating another range, then coming back and activating the original cell again but that didn't work..
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Update: Data Validation has nothing to do with the behavior. It does not update if you have started any edit (i.e. double click on a cell) versus a single click.

Comment: Just another thought-If I could simulate a ESC keypress (java keycode 27?) that seems like it would solve the problem as well. I couldn't find a simple way to do that in the above script.

Comment: Would you clarify something for me - if the data validation includes the term "Competent", then why would you want to run the script/function? What other scripts are running, any OnEdit/OnChange?, any custom functions?

Comment: It would seem that the blue box appears when a cell is being edited - the blue box shows you the cell reference. It's a combination of Formula Preview (F9) and zooming in (a lot). The use of the script in conjunction with data validation seems odd in itself, and may be contributing to the problem. It's hard to comment further without seeing the whole spreadsheet - which I invite you to share.